# AVFoundation how to add watermark with specified time and duration

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add a watermark to a video using AVFoundation with specified frame and duration. I can't find the answer from Google and tutorial. A Post on StackOverflow [How to watermark your video with different images and different CMTimes using AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166433/how-to-watermark-your-video-with-different-images-and-different-cmtimes-using-av) doesn't solve the problem. It just change opacity from start time to end time. Do you have any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a watermark in a captured video on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932041/how-can-i-add-a-watermark-in-a-captured-video-on-ios)

Comment: I think you will got answer from [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932041/how-can-i-add-a-watermark-in-a-captured-video-on-ios?lq=1

Comment: Thank @Desdenova kindness, I just want to add watermark to video for segment of video, not add watermark for the whole duration.

Comment: I want to set duration of the watermark. The article above demonstrates how to add watermark during the whole video playback.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: I didn't find the answer. I think AVFoundation can not do the the job. FFmpeg maybe an answer. Convert the video to frames and then add watermark to specified frame is an alternative method.@Scott F

Comment: @HeavenSword Have you found solution? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @HeavenSword i have same problem. if you get solution please post answer how to add water mark at specific time and duration.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [addBoundaryTimeObserver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388027-addboundarytimeobserver)

```
// Define the times at which you want to trigger events
let specificTimes: [CMTime] = [
    CMTime(seconds: 10.0, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), // Example time
    CMTime(seconds: 30.0, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))  // Another example time
]

// Add a boundary time observer
let timeObserverToken = player.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: specificTimes, queue: .main) {
    // This block of code will be executed when the player's current time crosses any of the specified times.
    // You can run your code here.
}

// Later, when you're done observing or when the player is no longer needed:
player.removeTimeObserver(timeObserverToken)
```