# How to use AVFoundation to apply a different text for different segments of a video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I'm trying to watermark a video's elapsed time onto the video frames. But I could only render a static text using `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` and `CALayer` into for the entire video duration.

How can I apply change the text that is overlaid on the video every second?

Similar questions in Stack Overflow hasn't been answered too

- [AVFoundation how to add watermark with specified time and
  duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301809/avfoundation-how-to-add-watermark-with-specified-time-and-duration?lq=1)
- [How to watermark your video with different images and different
  CMTimes using
  AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166433/how-to-watermark-your-video-with-different-images-and-different-cmtimes-using-av)

Comment: have found the solution? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

you just need to CABasicAnimation and add your title layer to it. Just check it out to changing the needed parameters its working fine. I Have done it in my one of project

```
CATextLayer *title = [CATextLayer layer];
// code for title layer setting
// code for the opacity animation which will remove the text
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[animation setDuration:0];
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[animation setBeginTime:1];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[title addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```